# sudo apt-get upgrade problem

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, system-installation, dpkg, latex

After upgrading to 14.04 L version, I have problems upgrading my system. I cannot figure out the problem by googling. Thank you very much for your help!

Here is the error information:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-pae
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.4fr8oCjd
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmodern:
 lmodern depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lmodern (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kile:
 kile depends on texliveNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    -latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kile (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkgNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              : dependency problems prevent configuration of pgf:
 pgf depends on tex-common (>= 2.00); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pgf depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 pgf depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pgf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on pgf (>= 1.00-1); however:
  Package pgf is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-recommended:
 texlive-generic-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-generic-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-pstricks depends on pgf; however:
  Package pgf is not configured yet.
 texlive-pstricks depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prosper:
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-pstricks; however:
  Package texlive-pstricks is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on tex-common (>= 1.10); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package prosper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base-doc:
 texlive-latex-base-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended-doc:
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks-doc:
 texlive-pstricks-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tipa:
 tipa depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 tipa depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 lmodern
 tex-gyre
 texlive-latex-base
 kile
 texlive-latex-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 pgf
 latex-beamer
 texlive-generic-recommended
 texlive-pstricks
 prosper
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive
 texlive-extra-utils
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-latex-base-doc
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc
 texlive-pstricks-doc
 tipa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22977/discussion-on-question-by-anand-sudo-apt-get-upgrade-problem).

Answer (score 2):

First, start with a fresh install.

Then run this command in the terminal, it will upgrade everything, remove old packages: 'sudo apt full-upgrade'

You can run 'autoclean' after, if you like.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks RCline7, I am doing that now. It will take sometime.

Comment: Here are the errors:

Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 lmodern
 tex-gyre
 texlive-latex-base
 kile
 texlive-latex-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 pgf
 latex-beamer
 texlive-generic-recommended
 texlive-pstricks
 prosper
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive
 texlive-extra-utils
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-latex-base-doc
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc
 texlive-pstricks-doc
 tipa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)